# How to use Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp inside a windows service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I'm trying to do self-hosting API on .NET running as windows service. Microsoft documentation suggests that using OWIN is the most up-to-date approach.

When we talk about Console Application, usage is quite clear:

```
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: Config.baseAddress))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Application is running.");
  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close.");
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It simply keeps running until key is pressed, then **using** takes care of the cleanup. But how to use it in service? I assume it needs to be initialized in **OnStart()** method and disposed with **OnStop()**. But how it is done exactly?